# i am using ngx toastr in angular 8 its showing below error if anyone knowns the solution tell me

Tags: angular, ngx-toastr

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ToastrService]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ToastrService]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ToastrService!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ToastrService]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ToastrService]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ToastrService!
at NullInjector.get (core.js:855)
at resolveToken (core.js:17514)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:17440)
at StaticInjector.get (core.js:17266)
at resolveToken (core.js:17514)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:17440)
at StaticInjector.get (core.js:17266)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30393)
at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:31578)
at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:734)
at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
at zone-evergreen.js:858
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)

Comment: It looks you didnt import ToastrModule

Answer (score 0):

Import `ToastrModule` in your AppModule:

```js
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        ToastrModule.forRoot({
          positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
          progressAnimation: 'decreasing',
          preventDuplicates: true,
          progressBar: true,
        })
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: i had imported toastrModule in the appModule. dont know why i am getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using the wrong version of ngx-toastr for your version of angular. Check which version is compatible here https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr#dependencies